# Unit testing apache beam job

Tags: python, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

I have a very simple dataflow job and I want to write unit tests. Sadly, there are no good examples what is the best way approach.

Here is the code

```py
import logging
from datetime import datetime
from re import sub

import apache_beam as beam
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import GoogleCloudOptions
from beam_nuggets.io import relational_db


class BeamOptions(PipelineOptions):
    @classmethod
    def _add_argparse_args(cls, parser):
        parser.add_argument(
            "--bigquery_input_table",
            help="A table from BigQuery to process",
            default="bigquery_input_table_empty",
        )
        parser.add_argument(
            "--bigquery_project", help="Project with BigQuery data", default="foo"
        )
        parser.add_argument(
            "--bigquery_dataset", help="Dataset from BigQuery", default="bar"
        )
        parser.add_argument(
            "--bucket", help="GCS Bucket for temporary files", default="model-foo-dev"
        )
        parser.add_argument("--db_password", help="Password for profiles DB", default="postgres")
        parser.add_argument("--db_host", help="host for profiles DB", default="localhost")
        parser.add_argument("--db_port", help="port for profiles DB", default=5432)


class BeamFeed:
    def __init__(self):
        logging.info("fetching BeamOptions")
        self.pipe_opt = BeamOptions()
        all_options = self.pipe_opt.get_all_options()
        self.bigquery_input_table = all_options["bigquery_input_table"]
        self.bigquery_project = all_options["bigquery_project"]
        self.bigquery_dataset = all_options["bigquery_dataset"]

        self.google_cloud_options = self.pipe_opt.view_as(GoogleCloudOptions)
        self.google_cloud_options.job_name = "model-foo-data-preparation-" + sub(
            r"[^0-9]", "-", str(datetime.now().isoformat())
        )
        self.google_cloud_options.staging_location = "gs://" + all_options["bucket"] + "/staging"
        self.google_cloud_options.temp_location = "gs://" + all_options["bucket"] + "/temp"
        self.pg_config = relational_db.SourceConfiguration(
            drivername="postgresql+pg8000",
            host=all_options["db_host"],
            port=all_options["db_port"],
            username="postgres",
            database="postgres",
            password=all_options["db_password"],
        )
        self.table_config = relational_db.TableConfiguration(
            name="users", primary_key_columns=["id"]
        )

    def run(self, pipeline):
        """runs whole beam job pipeline"""
        users_bq = beam.io.BigQuerySource(
            dataset=self.bigquery_dataset,
            project=self.bigquery_project,
            table=self.bigquery_input_table,
            validate=True,
        )

        users_info = (
            pipeline
            | "read_users" >> beam.io.Read(users_bq)
            | "map_by_user_id" >> beam.Map(lambda usr: {"id": usr["id"], "value": usr})
        )

        users_info | "Writing to DB table" >> relational_db.Write(
            source_config=self.pg_config, table_config=self.table_config
        )


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    logging.info("starting BeamFeed process")
    beam_job = BeamFeed()
    with beam.Pipeline(options=beam_job.pipe_opt) as pipeline:
        beam_job.run(pipeline)
```

And the UT attempt

```
import pytest

import apache_beam
from apache_beam.testing.test_pipeline import TestPipeline
from apache_beam.testing.util import assert_that, equal_to
from apache_beam.transforms import Create, FlatMap
from apache_beam.options.pipeline_options import PipelineOptions
from apache_beam.runners.direct.direct_runner import DirectRunner

from bla import beam, BeamFeed, BeamOptions



@pytest.fixture
def bg_mock(mocker):
    # apache_beam.Create(
    #     [{"id": "8d73fda0-00b8-4084-bb8a-eea0f5bca46a", "foo": 1}]
    # )
    return mocker.patch("apache_beam.io.BigQuerySource")


def test_empty_profile_generation(bg_mock):
    pipeline = TestPipeline(runner=DirectRunner())
    beam_job = BeamFeed()
    beam_job.run(pipeline)
    pipeline.run()
```

I'm not sure what is the best approach to testing Dataflow jobs. Just integrations testing and no mocks? With given mock pytest fails `[1]    16845 abort`

Comment: I found one of the best source of test inspiration is the Apache Beam source itself: https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/examples/complete
Which also includes some tests. You will want to disable saving the main session. To debug your "run" method you need to mock beam.io.BigQuerySource but also configure the mock to return some data. I'd move as much as possible to small functions and test them separately.

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems there are no examples where they test IO (source) - they just separate the logic and test it.

Comment: test_autocomplete_it is an integration test. Whereas other tests pass in the test data, by having separated the logic as you mentioned. You could use that as an inspiration to separate your code more. I personally find your question difficult to properly answer because there are many aspects just in your example code that can be tested.

Answer (score 4):

I share the opinion from @de1, Apache Beam have some really good tests to inspire your own.

According to what you are looking for, I think there are a couple of files in the SDK code of Apache Beam that will help you a lot to setup your unit testing.

- [bigquery_io_read_pipeline.py](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_io_read_pipeline.py)
- [bigquery_io_read_it_test.py](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_io_read_it_test.py)

Also, if you want to see more tests for BigQuery take a look at [this](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp).

A quick overview of how they make the testing:

- The pipeline is setup with a validation ([assert_that with equal_to](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/0851849dcfe9b8088d69a5bdd3b55f7806b83ea9/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_io_read_pipeline.py#L72)) with the use of [TestPipeline](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.16.0/apache_beam.testing.test_pipeline.html?highlight=testpipeline#module-apache_beam.testing.test_pipeline), this may be for a extra level of testing directly into the Job, which for your case may not be required, you can keep using [Pipeline](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.16.0/apache_beam.pipeline.html?#apache-beam-pipeline-module).
- The test use the [TestPipeline](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.16.0/apache_beam.testing.test_pipeline.html?highlight=testpipeline#module-apache_beam.testing.test_pipeline), and also [PipelineStateMatcher](https://beam.apache.org/releases/pydoc/2.16.0/apache_beam.testing.pipeline_verifiers.html?highlight=pipelinestatematcher#module-apache_beam.testing.pipeline_verifiers) to validate and verify that the pipeline job terminated in a expected state.
- Is required to make your own setup to have testing tables that can be [used for the test](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/0851849dcfe9b8088d69a5bdd3b55f7806b83ea9/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_io_read_it_test.py#L39). In this case there are 4 tables, but they actually [use only 1](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/0851849dcfe9b8088d69a5bdd3b55f7806b83ea9/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_io_read_it_test.py#L58), so if you just create 1 or 2 tables I think is cool. This must be according to your needs.
- Finally the test in run with the [unittest.main](https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/0851849dcfe9b8088d69a5bdd3b55f7806b83ea9/sdks/python/apache_beam/io/gcp/bigquery_io_read_it_test.py#L63) function.

I hope this sample serves you to create your own Jobs and unittests.